# SQL if two date columns match, then give certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull data into a table and have two date fields. "INSERT_Date" AND "Take_Date".

What i am trying to do is have an IF statement like such

If INSERT_Date = Take_Date then 'Current' ELSE 'Future'

Here is my attempt at it, but couldnt get past this part without errors.

```
Select (Case when INSERT_Date = Take_Date ) then 'Current'
        else 'Future' end) as Type

From tablename
```

Comment: You have a wayward right parenthesis (`)`) prior to your `THEN`. No parenthenses are needed in this statement, so you could just remove them all.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `)`there. You can just write you query as

```
Select Case when INSERT_Date = Take_Date  then 'Current'
        else 'Future' end as [Type]
From tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    select 
         case when INSERT_Date = Take_Date then 'Current'
         else 'Future' 
   end as [Type]
```